# Using directive in Derived Class changes inheritance to Public

Tags: c++, inheritance, protected, using-directives

**A very simple question but yet confusing:**

Why does a using directive change the inheritance!?
This compiles with Comeau.

I have read that a using directive (decleration?) makes the variable public, but why?
What I want is just a nice method not to write always `this->x` inside B...?

```
class A{
protected:
    int x;
public:
};

class B: public A {
public:
    using A::x;
};

int main(){
  B b;
  b.x = 2;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to write `this->x` inside B...

Comment: OK , jeah I have templates actually, and I can avoid using this-> by simply adding in the right "section" (private,protected, public) (to not change the inheritance) section a using decleration... thats the way...

Answer (score 2):

You are the class designer, you are allowed to make the variable public.

If you don't want that, don't put the `using` in the public section.

And you don't have to use `this->x` in the derived class, unless the base class is a template.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does a stupid using directive change the inheritance!?

Because you've declared the `using` declaration (not directive) `public`. Make it `protected` or `private` if you don't want it to be generally accessible.

> What I want is just a nice method not to write always `this->x` inside `B`...?

Usually, and in your example, you don't have to. You'll only need to do that if `A` and `B` are both templates, and the base class is dependent (i.e. depends on the derived class's template parameters). In that case, a private `using` will allow you to avoid writing `this->x`.